# Automatic number of footnotes?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is there a way for R-Markdown (or, more specifically, bookdown) to automatically number footnotes, like it already does for figures? I am working on a book-length project, and it would be convenient not to have to renumber all my footnotes every time I add or delete one.

Answer (score 9):

The number is automatic, just use a different name after `[^ ]`.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

footnote 1 [^anyname]

[^anyname]: Here is the first 

footnote 2 [^anyname2]

[^anyname2]: Here is the second
```

[image]

Comment: It is worth nothing that `[^](inline footnotes)` do not require a number or name at all.